# (Net worth) combined annual output of Japan, Germany and UK?

Tags: macroeconomics

The following is a quote from old news. What’s the meaning of “combined annual output of Germany, Japan and Britain”? **Which output?**

> The Fed said Thursday that U.S. households' net worth tumbled by $11 trillion (in 2008)-- a decline in a single year that equals the combined annual output of Japan, Germany and UK.

Comment: My reading of the IMF numbers has GDP in Germany in 2018 of almost $\$4.0tr$, in Japan of almost $\$5.0tr$ and in the UK of just over $\$2.8tr$, wich together add up to slightly more than $\$11tr$ but less than $\$12tr$.  Using PPP$\$$ would make the three a little higher still

Comment: Thanks. I forget to say that the figure is just for 2008 when financial crisis occured.

Comment: But, Henry, you are correct. I searched the GDP of the three nations in 2008 and it is about 11.681